# How to switching between tabs in JSP and Spring in the background without lose the changes

Tags: spring, jsp

I am working with spring and I have a page have 3 different tabs, and when I switch for another tab I am losing the changes I did in the previos tab. Any help?

Comment: which type of tabs you are using? We normally prefer `jquery tabs` which just the divs with UI effect on the same page. So, even if the tabs are switched, the data is maintained.

Comment: Hello, Thanks. Yes, finally I came up with that approach